# invert result (set) of procedure to json format

Tags: json, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have `Procedure` returns Result set (`SELECT ...`)

is there a way to invert the result to json format without changes of existsing procedure

something like use of temp table is work, but i am search for something like `SET` Option that affect the environment

for example :

```
SELECT * FROM TableName FOR JSON AUTO
```

but my select statement is inside procedure.

i can use

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (...)
INSERT @t () 
EXEC myProc
SELECT * FROM @t FOR JSON AUTO
```

but the result of `myProc` is not Constantly...

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will help us help you here. Without all of that, how do you propose we help you?

Comment: BTW you probably mean *convert*, not invert. Even so, why use JSON in the *database* instead of the client? You aren't exposing the database to the public internet (I hope). In all other cases, the client can make that conversion easily. Even in SQL though, you can use `FOR JSON` to convert results to JSON